# How to do an =Countif( in Business Objects

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to count the number of times a particular "Policy Status Code" occurs in a dataset. I can get the report to do this count but only by writing along, and ridiculously complex formula. I want to get BOBJ to essentially do a =countif(Dataset[Policy Status Code], Result[Policy Status Code])

[Current semi-functional report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBYu4.png)

I wrote an 11 part nested if statement but it will break if I get a policy status code that I didn't account for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirement correctly there is most certainly an easier way. You should be able to just create a **Var Policy Count** variable to count the policy numbers like this...

```
=Count([Policy Number])
```

I used eFashion data for my example and created a **Var Store Count** variable corresponding to your **Var Policy Count** variable...

```
=Count([Store name])
```

Here is the result.

[image]

No complicated If statement and new values will be counted without issue.

Comment: Yes sir, this is correct. I feel like an idiot but thanks for the help.